# JQuery - click to show div then hide again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following div, which is hidden:

```
<div class="showDescription 73" style="display:none;">blah blah blah</div>
```

and then at the side of it:

```
<div class="more" divtoshow="73" style="cursor:pointer">more...</div>
```

I want to click the div with class `more` and it shows the hidden div, then change the word `more...` `to less...`, remove class `more`, add a class `canHide` to it so when clicked again it will hide the div again. Simple stuff. It becomes this:

```
<div class="canHide" divtoshow="73" style="cursor:pointer">less...</div>
```

When i click the word more the hidden div shows and adds a class `canHide`, but when clicking it again nothing happens and I don't know why.

JQuery - this section works as it should:

```
$('.more').click(function() { // show hidden div
    var classId = $(this).attr('divToShow');
    $("." + classId).fadeIn();
    $(this).removeClass('more');
    $(this).addClass('canHide');
    $(this).html('less...');
});
```

This section does nothing??

```
$('.canHide').click(function() { // hide shown div
    var classId = $(this).attr('divToShow');
    $("." + classId).fadeOut();
    alert('hey'); // for test purposes only
    $(this).removeClass('canHide');
    $(this).addClass('more');
    $(this).html('more...');
});
```

Here be a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/s2apg/)

Comment: You could use pure CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/s2apg/7/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**this might be easier**

```
$('.more').click(function() { 
    // show/hide element before .more && toggle text
    $(this).html($(this).html()=='▼'?'▲':'▼').prev('.showDescription').stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

It also removes the corresponding attributes between the `more` link and `content`, as it makes them unnecessary. *ie divtoshow/class 73*

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/zXz3c/

**update:** here's each piece broken down

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    // get element
    $(this)
    //if html = ▼ then it should now be ▲, or if html = ▲ then it should now be ▼; else it should be ▼
    .html($(this).html()=='▼'?'▲':'▼')
    //get previous element by class
    .prev('.showDescription')
    //clear its queue to prevent buildup
    .stop()
    //fadeIn if it's hidden or fadeOut if it's visible
    .fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thats really cool! However, it only works for me 'kind of' - I've moved away from 'more...' & 'less...' to ascii characters - and can't get it to work - try this: http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/zXz3c/9/

Comment: not a problem, I've updated the fiddle. the problem is that the entity needs to be converted back to text, or the entities needs to be supplied as text instead of the html code for them. *I did the latter.*

Comment: Excellent!! I hadn't thought of using .next() & .prev() - works perfectly

Comment: Thanks done that - one last thing, if you have time, can you please explain the line in your answer, what each section of it does? No problem if not, I'd just like to understand what is happening

Comment: no problem, broke it down in the fiddle piece by piece and described each part, and updated the answer as well.

Comment: Cannot thank you enough mate!! That's really, really helpful - kudos

Answer (score 8):

You're changing the class, so that handler (which is bound at runtime), has no idea that that new class exists. Use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '.canHide', function() { // hide shown div

});
```

`document` should be the element that contains the element with the `.canHide` class and is there at runtime, but since I can't see your HTML, `document` is a safe bet.

Comment: Awesome, my bad, I should have known that - I had to add it to both functions otherwise it had a fit! Will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: This seems like a band-aid for the issue, adding complexity instead of simplifying.

Comment: @FiLeVeR10 -- What? What band-aid? Event delegation is a necessity.

Comment: @tymeJV no, it *can* be, most of the time it's overused or an afterthought.

Comment: @tymeJV I've added an answer that solves the entire issue in one line of jquery inside of a click function. Just to show you that, in this case, delegation is not a necessity. Neither is most of the original code.